# Momentum conservation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, string

https://youtu.be/ErMSHiQRnc8?si=-8Wgqj-6M_5qYySP
I saw this video and I wonder how the man can move on the frictionless surface with ball attached to the string, by rotating it in horizontal and vertical direction and releasing it suddenly, and again grabbing it so that the impulse generated by the string will make him move forward.
But since initially momentum was zero in horizontal direction then it should be conserved and be zero all the time in horizontal direction as no force acts in that direction. Then please explain How will it happen???

Comment: you are talking about an animation,video and you can pose your question at the site so the people responsible for the physics answer you.

Answer (score 0):

Position is not a conserved quantity. You can change your position by a finite length on a real plane of ice by slowly moving a mass forward, your position fixed by rest friction, and fast reunite with conserved center of mass and no friction.

The other method is using a fast rotating wheel with horizontal axis. Since you are not able to rotate the axis in the horizontal plane without a fixed direction of your feet on ground, the wheel rotates you, as long as you are exerting a torque (inverse of precession). Make a half turn, then move the wheel over head to the other side and continue.

What you watch in the video is a collection of usual technics in winter sports or even flying objects like a free falling cat rotating its body by using the tail as a spinning top for an exact turn by $180°$.